# Calculate values in org-mode attributes?

Tags: org-mode, calc

Is there a package that lets you calculate values contained (for example) in #+attributes (or some other "variable"-like syntax)? I'm trying to avoid spreadsheets, because my list is relatively simple:

```
* Shopping list
** eggs
#+price: 1$
#+quantity: 6
** carrots
#+price: 0.2$
#+quantity: 10

#+total: 8$
```

The last line would be then generated as the list changes following the user-defined formula (for each item add $price * $quantity).

Does such a thing exist? Apologies if any of the above assumptions are wrong - would really appreciate any hints.

Comment: I think you'd be better off making `price` and `quantity` propertiers: there is a well-defined [API](https://orgmode.org/org.html#Using-the-Property-API) to retrieve such properties that you can leverage. I'm less clear on how to report the total: the main question there is are you going to use it for further calculations or is it just a summary for human eyes? You may be able to use [Column view](https://orgmode.org/org.html#Column-View) for that. But the simplest solution is [The spreadsheet](https://orgmode.org/org.html#The-Spreadsheet): I don't quite understand your reluctance to use it.

Comment: I thought that when dealing with "unstructured data" where properties don't repeat across all items listing each attribute/property under headers may be preferred to spreadsheets/tables (a bit like relational/document databases). But if there is no easy way to calculate them, I'll stick to tables (or sc-im, visidata or even libreoffice).

Comment: It's not so much that it's hard to calculate: it's more that you are probably going to end up with an ad-hoc, one-off program that is only useful in very special cases. The table approach OTOH is built-in and general enough for many purposes: it's certainly more than good enough for this problem.